# Moving rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I created dataframe, indexed by dates in ascending order and one column 'A'. I would like to create a column 'B', which is the standard deviation of the last five value of the column 'A' and a column 'C' which is the number corresponding to the row

```
i=5
while i<(len(df.index)) :
    df['B'][i]=df['A'][i-5:i-1].std()
    i=i+1
df['C']=df.get_loc(df.index.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))`
```

This code is not optimal and slow. And for column 'C' that does not work.

Comment: for column B just use `pd.rolling_std`:  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.rolling_std.html  I don't understand column C, are you just replicating the index???

Comment: Thanks John - Yes, I just want to know which row on the table I am. If I write df.index, it returns the date, as that's my index.

Comment: probably you just want to do `reset_index`